# Create an NSPopover with SWT Java

Tags: java, objective-c, cocoa, swt

I am trying to create an NSPopover for the SWT Cocoa port on Mac. [Here](https://gist.github.com/marteinn/d4842e3d404d6bac489c) is the way to do it in Objective-C, but I was wondering how I can achieve this same thing using SWT. The Popover looks like this:

[image: Popover in Xcode]

There is no 'NSPopover' in the cocoa port of SWT so it does not exist in the API.

How can I create this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Rectangle;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Region;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;

public class PopOver {

    public static void main(String[] a) {
        Display display = new Display();
        final Shell shell = new Shell(display,SWT.NO_TRIM);

        Region region = new Region();
        region.add(new Rectangle(0,0,200,200));
        region.add(new int[]{200,90,220,100,200,110});
        shell.setRegion(region);

        shell.setSize(region.getBounds().width, region.getBounds().height);
        shell.setBackground(display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_DARK_GRAY));


        shell.open();

        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
                display.sleep();
            }
        }
        display.dispose();
    }

}
```

This is the result:
[image]